# Preventing A Table Column To Be Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with TV shows as shown below:
[image]

When I click the column for "Show Name", "Episode" or "Date Aired" a modal pops up so that I can edit the details of the show. Each one of the icons on the last column has a purpose so if I was to click one of them then it would still class it as clicking the column which therefore highlights the entire row which I do not want.

This is my jQuery for highlighting the row:

```
$('tbody').on("click","tr",function(e) {
    $('tbody tr').not(this).removeClass('selected_click_cell');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected_click_cell');
});
```

Is there a way to still highlight the entire row including the last column even if the icons on the last columns are clicked? Alternatively, is it possible to only highlight the first 3 columns when clicked?

Comment: Your issue is the click bubbling up the DOM i believe changing the z-index of those icons to be above the column will fix it or another route is to prevent default if i remember correctly.

Comment: @Darkrum Hi, how do I go about doing the `z-index`? I've tried setting the `<td>` with a `z-index` of `1`. I also tried creating another CSS property with a `z-index` of `1` but it's still not working. It's still highlighting the whole row.

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?